# How to Create a Lightweight CSS Image Gallery with Different Image than Thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, html, css

tl;dr - using this (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tab_img_gallery.asp) simplistic css / html / javascript code combo, but am stuck at making the "expanded image" a completely different image than the thumbnail itself.

Is this possible? How would I edit the below code for that tweak?

Context: Recreating my art site in hand-coded HTML, and my thumbnails are cropped in photoshop as i have a personal dislike for whole-images-as-a-thumbnail aesthetic reasons. Code below.

```css
 <!-- CSS -->
 /* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */
.column img {
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* The expanding image container (positioning is needed to position the close button and the text) */
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

/* Expanding image text */
#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Closable button inside the image */
.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
 <!-- HTML -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_nature.jpg" alt="Nature" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_lights.jpg" alt="Lights" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- The expanding image container -->
<div class="container">
  <!-- Close the image -->
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>

  <!-- Expanded image -->
  <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">

  <!-- Image text -->
  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
```

```js
 <!-- Javascript -->
function myFunction(imgs) {
  // Get the expanded image
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  // Get the image text
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  // Use the same src in the expanded image as the image being clicked on from the grid
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  // Use the value of the alt attribute of the clickable image as text inside the expanded image
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  // Show the container element (hidden with CSS)
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

there are so many tags missing in your code like all `<head><style>Your Css Code</style></head>`

```
<script>JS code</script>
```

The things You are writing like `<!-- Image text -->` this <- that all are called comments and not executed at any condition

## And Here is the Right code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

/* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Style the images inside the grid */
.column img {
  opacity: 0.8; 
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* The expanding image container */
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

/* Expanding image text */
#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

/* Closable button inside the expanded image */
.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <h2>Stackover Flow</h2>
  <p>Click on the images below:</p>
</div>

<!-- The four columns -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/06/19/21/24/the-road-815297__340.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/beautiful-autumn-scene-hintersee-lake-260nw-747646759.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
  <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction(imgs) {
  var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
  expandImg.src = imgs.src;
  imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
  expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "there are so many tags missing in your code" — They only omitted boilerplate. Nothing they left out is required to understand the question.

Comment: "that all are called comments and not executed at any condition" — Given they wrote plain english inside the comment syntax, it is pretty clear they understand that already

Comment: "And Here is the Right code" — That appears to be identical to the code the OP posted with the comments stripped out. It doesn't address the problem described in the question at all.

Answer (score -1):

what about object-fit: cover; for example documentation here [object-fit examples](https://alligator.io/css/cropping-images-object-fit/)

Comment: That wouldn't address the problem. The question is specifically about using a different image file for the expanded image. It isn't about scaling the image they already have.